# Generating a dynamic canvas id for chart.js with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js

I am creating an app that generates graphs using Chart.js when a button is pressed. I can generate a graph when the button is pressed, but the canvas id only works when it is static. I would like to do is something like this:

```
     <canvas *ngFor="let t of type" 
             id = "{{t.id}}" 
             height="500">
     </canvas>
```

This is all I can get to work right now.

```
     <canvas id = "graphing1" 
             height="500">
     </canvas>
```

Using a div to check the ngFor loop, it prints this: **graphing1**

```
     <div *ngFor="let t of type" id = {{t.id}}>
             {{t.id}}
     </div>
```

This is the Chart.js in typescript. I checked my variable with a console.log and I get the same output as the div (graphing1).

```
console.log(this.type[this.count].id) //emits graphing1
for(this.count = 0; this.count < this.type.length; this.count++ ){
this.chart[this.count] = new Chart(this.type[this.count].id, { ... })
```

So I know the variable is emitting the correct information, but I can't figure out how to put this information into a canvas id.

Comment: Encapsulate chartjs in a component and use a template reference variable to initialize your chartjs objects.